# Secure Way to store Tokens and sensitives informations in front end(Angular 8)

Tags: angular, cookies, jwt, local-storage, session-cookies

I'm using Angular 8 and I want to store my access token and some token by using cookies.

So I tried to store my tokens in cookies, I worked on a first time but after I saw that when I want to log out and clear my cookies, they do not delete all the time and some error with 401 status(unAuthorized) appeared. I'm using ngx-cookie-service. Do you know a good way and a secure one to store tokens? This is my AuthService:

```
public login(username: string, password: string) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append('username', username);
    params.append('password', password);
    params.append('grant_type', 'password');
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
      Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa('Andricebrain:Aqwzsx1995')
    });

    const options = {
      headers
    };
    this.httpClient
      .post(
        environment.baseUrlOauth + '/oauth/token',
        params.toString(),
        options
      )
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.getAuthorities(data);
          console.log(data);

          // this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        },
        error => {
          this.toastr.error('Erreur', 'Login ou mot de passe incorrect');
        }
      );
  }


  getAuthorities(token): boolean {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa('Andricebrain:Aqwzsx1995')
    });
    const options = {
      headers
    };
    this.httpClient
      .get(
        environment.baseUrlOauth +
          '/oauth/check_token?token=' +
          token.access_token,
        options
      )
      .toPromise()
      .then(
        data => {
          console.log(token);

          this.saveToken(token, data);
          // return true;
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
          alert('Error : get authorities');
          // return false;
        }
      );
    return false;
  }

  saveToken(token, check) {
    const expireDate = new Date().getTime() + 1000 * token.expires_in;
    this.cookie.set('access_token', token.access_token, expireDate);
    this.cookie.set('refresh_token', token.refresh_token);
    this.cookie.set('authorities', check.authorities);
    this.cookie.set('user', JSON.stringify(check.user[0]));
    this.authorities = check.authorities;
    this.user = check.user[0];
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  }

// TokenInterceptorService

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      tap((ev: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (ev instanceof HttpResponse) {
          // console.log('processing response', ev);
          // if (ev.status === 200) {
          //   this.toastr.success('L\'opération s\'est bien passée :-)', 'Succès');
          // }
          //
          // if (ev.status === 201) {
          //   this.toastr.success('Votre objet a bien été créé :-)', 'Succès');
          // }
        }
      }),
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (error.status === 401) {
          if (error.error.error === 'invalid_token') {
            // TODO: Token refreshing
            // this.toastr.info('Nous tentons de vous reconnecter !', 'Reconnexion');
            this.authService.refreshToken();

            const token = this.cookie.get('access_token');
            if (token) {
              // this.toastr.info('Reconnexion', 'Nous avons presque réussi !');
              req = req.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                  Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
                }
              });
            }
          } else {
            // Logout from account or do some other stuff
            this.appService.logout();
          }

          if (error.error.error === 'unauthorized') {
            // TODO: Token refreshing
            // this.toastr.info('Vous ne pouvez pas accéder à cette ressource !', 'Accès Refusé');
          }
        }

/*
        if (error.status === 409) {
           this.toastr.error('Une donnée pose problème', 'Conflit');
         }

        if (error.status === 400) {
           this.toastr.error('L\'objet qui a été envoyé est mal construit !', 'Mauvaise requête');
         }
*/

        return throwError(error);
      })
    );
  }
```

If you can find a secure solution it will be great

Answer (score 0):

One accepted answer when it comes to storing token in the browser, is using JWT.
They can be encrypted, signed or both. Plus, they work better with mobile browsers than cookies. This library may help you to get a correct JWT setup for your angular application.
https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt

Your error with cookies may be due to the fact that they are not set in the correct path. Remember that ngx-cookie will set your cookies on the current path of the URL and that you may prefer to set them at the root.

```
cookieService.set( 'test', 'Hello World', 1, "/" );
```

Bon courage !